# Migrating Infinispan xml configuration from 6.x to 7.x

Tags: java, migration, infinispan, xml-configuration, jboss-cache

I've been using Infinispan 6.x and I have a couple of XML configuration files. Now I want to migrate to 7.x, but I'm having exceptions when the new version tries to parse the old configuration files. Here is my configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<infinispan xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:schemaLocation="urn:infinispan:config:6.0 http://www.infinispan.org/schemas/infinispan-config-6.0.xsd">
  <global>
    <globalJmxStatistics enabled="false" mBeanServerLookup="dz.lab.cache.infinispan.DummyMBeanServer$DummyLoockup" />
  </global>
  <default>    
    <eviction strategy="NONE" />
    <expiration lifespan="-1" maxIdle="-1" />
    <clustering mode="local">
      <hash>
        <groups enabled="true" />
      </hash>
    </clustering>
    <transaction transactionManagerLookupClass="org.infinispan.transaction.lookup.JBossStandaloneJTAManagerLookup" transactionMode="TRANSACTIONAL" lockingMode="OPTIMISTIC" />
    <invocationBatching enabled="true" />
    <locking supportsConcurrentUpdates="true" />    
  </default>
</infinispan>
```

and the full stacktrace:

```
org.infinispan.commons.CacheConfigurationException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[7,11]
Message: Unexpected element 'global' encountered
    at org.infinispan.configuration.parsing.ParseUtils.unexpectedElement(ParseUtils.java:35)
    at org.infinispan.configuration.parsing.Parser70.readElement(Parser70.java:96)
    at org.infinispan.configuration.parsing.ParserRegistry.parseElement(ParserRegistry.java:133)
    at org.infinispan.configuration.parsing.ParserRegistry.parse(ParserRegistry.java:115)
    at org.infinispan.configuration.parsing.ParserRegistry.parse(ParserRegistry.java:102)
    at org.infinispan.configuration.parsing.ParserRegistry.parse(ParserRegistry.java:89)
    ... 30 more
```

How do I migrate this configuration? I can't find hints on the [official user guide](http://infinispan.org/docs/7.0.x/user_guide/user_guide.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<infinispan
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="urn:infinispan:config:7.0 http://www.infinispan.org/schemas/infinispan-config-7.0.xsd"
        xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:7.0">
    <cache-container name="default" default-cache="defaultCache">
        <serialization />
        <jmx>
            <property name="enabled">true</property>
        </jmx>
        <local-cache name="defaultCache">
          ...
        </local-cache>
    </cache-container>
</infinispan>
```

See the schema for all the transaction, isolation, eviction etc. elements - those are very similar.

Comment: for the clustering i need to add this to the cache container just after the local cache declaration `<distributed-cache name="defaultCache"> <groups enabled="true"/> </distributed-cache>`

Comment: It looks like the boolean `supportsConcurrentUpdates` in `locking` is replaced by `concurrency-level` that indicates the number of threads !!

Comment: Not really. Concurrent updates (on single key) are always enabled now (you can check programmatic configuration which emits a warning when trying to set it). On the other hand, concurrency-level just passes expected number of concurrent updates *on all keys* to the underlying hashmaps, for fine-tuning of performance.

Answer (score 3):

Upgrade guide might be found [here](http://infinispan.org/docs/7.0.x/upgrading/upgrading.html#_upgrading_from_6_0_to_7_0). Please upgrade your [xml schema to 7.0](http://infinispan.org/schemas/infinispan-config-7.0.xsd) (or 7.1) and recreate your configuration. `global` xml element is now called `cache-container`, here is an [example](https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan/blob/e93eb352ed28f0cb2dea5b62f683e9f7a55cc268/spring/spring/src/test/resources/org/infinispan/spring/support/embedded/non-transactional-cache.xml).

Comment: it sounds like they renamed many things, i've similar problem with `<default />`!!