# Migration of infinispan 5 to infinspan 7

Tags: infinispan

I started using infinispan 5.3 and prepared a config file according to my needs. Now I want to migrate to infinispan 7. But I found many problems in finding the equivalent infinispan 7 config file. Please help me in finding the infinispan 7. But I found many problems in finding the equivalent infinispan 7 config file. This is my infinispan 5 configuration file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<infinispan
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="urn:infinispan:config:5.1 http://www.infinispan.org/schemas/infinispan-config-5.1.xsd"
      xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:5.1">

    <global>

        <asyncListenerExecutor
            factory="org.infinispan.executors.DefaultExecutorFactory">
            <properties>
                <property name="maxThreads" value="5" />
                <property name="threadNamePrefix"
                    value="AsyncListenerThread" />
            </properties>
        </asyncListenerExecutor>

        <asyncTransportExecutor
            factory="org.infinispan.executors.DefaultExecutorFactory">
            <properties>
                <property name="maxThreads" value="20" />
                <property name="threadNamePrefix"
                    value="AsyncSerializationThread" />
            </properties>
        </asyncTransportExecutor>

        <evictionScheduledExecutor
            factory="org.infinispan.executors.DefaultScheduledExecutorFactory">
            <properties>
                <property name="threadNamePrefix"
                    value="EvictionThread" />
            </properties>
        </evictionScheduledExecutor>

        <replicationQueueScheduledExecutor
            factory="org.infinispan.executors.DefaultScheduledExecutorFactory">
            <properties>
                <property name="threadNamePrefix"
                    value="ReplicationQueueThread" />
            </properties>
        </replicationQueueScheduledExecutor>

        <globalJmxStatistics enabled="false" jmxDomain="infinispan" />

        <transport clusterName="PC_SITE_1"
            distributedSyncTimeout="50000"
            transportClass="org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport"
            nodeName="">
            <properties>
                <property name="configurationFile"
                    value="./tmp/_clusterconfig/pc_jgroups_main.xml" />
            </properties>
        </transport>

        <serialization
            marshallerClass="org.infinispan.marshall.VersionAwareMarshaller"
            version="1.0" />


        <shutdown hookBehavior="DEFAULT" />

    </global>

    <default>
        <locking isolationLevel="READ_COMMITTED"
            lockAcquisitionTimeout="60000" writeSkewCheck="false"
            concurrencyLevel="5000" useLockStriping="false" />
        <jmxStatistics enabled="false" />
        <storeAsBinary enabled="true"/>
    </default>

    <namedCache name="GLOBAL_ASYNC_CACHE">

    <transaction
                       transactionManagerLookupClass="com.suntecgroup.tbms.container.services.cluster.ContainerCacheTxManagerLookup"
            syncRollbackPhase="false" syncCommitPhase="false"
            useEagerLocking="false" lockingMode="PESSIMISTIC"/>
      <clustering mode="replication">
           <!--<async useReplQueue="true" replQueueInterval="100"
            asyncMarshalling="true" replQueueMaxElements="10000" />-->
            <sync replTimeout="360000" />
           <stateTransfer timeout="360000"  fetchInMemoryState="true" />
      </clustering>
      <lazyDeserialization enabled="true" />
     </namedCache>
    <namedCache name="GLOBAL_ASYNC_STR_CACHE">
    <transaction transactionMode="NON_TRANSACTIONAL" />
        <clustering mode="replication">
            <sync replTimeout="360000" />
            <stateTransfer timeout="360000" fetchInMemoryState="true" />
        </clustering>
    </namedCache>

    <namedCache name="GLOBAL_ASYNC_STR_EVCT_CACHE">
    <transaction transactionMode="NON_TRANSACTIONAL" />
        <clustering mode="replication">
            <sync replTimeout="360000" />
            <stateTransfer timeout="360000" fetchInMemoryState="true" />
        </clustering>
    </namedCache>

    <namedCache name="LOCAL_CACHE">

    <transaction
            transactionManagerLookupClass="com.suntecgroup.tbms.container.services.cluster.ContainerCacheTxManagerLookup"
            syncRollbackPhase="false" syncCommitPhase="false"
            useEagerLocking="false" lockingMode="PESSIMISTIC"/>

    </namedCache>

</infinispan>
```

Comment: Here is a very similar topic: [Migrating Infinispan xml configuration from 6.x to 7.x] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28021468/migrating-infinispan-xml-configuration-from-6-x-to-7-x/28040287#28040287

Answer (score 1):

Threadpool settings are configured in  element, then you set to use them (bind by name) on the  element. This moved out of the  element (this was removed).

The default cache is not defined as it's own element but it is declared as just another cache in the  and then the cache-container defines which one is the default in an attribute.

Named caches with certain clustering modes have become its own elements,  etc.